# Faster than COUNTIFS?

Tags: excel, countif

I have worksheets that contain 100k-750k rows of text (each worksheet varies in rows#). I need to know if the text is found more than once.

Painfully slow! But here is the formula I am currently using:
=COUNTIF(BQ:BQ,BQ2)

Comment: Use a different program, when we were analysing large data we used SAS... Built the original trial in excel then did the real work in SAS - was 10 meg of solid numbers...

Comment: If you are only checking a single value then COUNTIF should be fast enough. But if you want to find all the values in BQ that appear more than once you need to use a different technique - I would suggest either Power Query or a UDF using Dictionary.

Comment: Or sort BQ and add a helper column that checks if the BQ cell in the row above is the same as the BQ cell in this row

Comment: @ Solar, I will eventually be making a data base to hold the data.

Comment: @ Charles, currently running this on mac. So, no power query available. I'll play around with your second suggestion. Thanks, Bret